# Optics, question on Thomas Young optics drawing, Young-Fresnel theory

Tags: optics, visible-light

In Fig. 4, in light cone ABC, there is what looks like the tips of a birds feathers from a wing (there are actually 10 corresponding to the primary feathers if you use this) in succession to the right of CH.  Does this follow Young-Fresnel theory geometry, if so, what are then triangular tips representing?  Also, I think Young writes they are duplicated on the left side of the light cone.  Are they in the theory?

In Young writing, he mentions the thicker breadth black lines are undulations, with more force, so I suspect higher amplitude of spherical wave is shown in what I mention.

[image: a]